# SQL query : select max of 2 columns of same row

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, select

```
Column1 | Column2
--------+-------- 
1       |    1
3       |    2
1       |    3
2       |    1
2       |    4
```

I want the max of column1 and after that the max of column2 : in this example --> 3 : 2

Comment: If you want the max of both column 1 and 2, the output should be 3 | 4, should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following :

```
select column1, column2
  from tab 
 where column1 = ( Select max(column1) from tab );
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/53bf2/1)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `order by`:

```
select column1, column2
from t
order by column1 desc, column2 desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

I see you are using MS Access, so this is phrased as:

```
select top (1) column1, column2
from t
order by column1 desc, column2 desc;
```

The only challenge with this approach is that is might return multiple rows, if you have duplicates in the data.  If this is an issue, either include a unique id as the last key in the `order by`:

```
order by column1 desc, column2 desc, id;
```

Or use aggregation:

```
select max(column1), max(column2)
from (select top (1) column1, column2
      from t
      order by column1 desc, column2 desc
     ) as t;
```

The `max()` only serves to reduce the result set to a single row (in the event of duplicates).  Because all the values from the subquery would be the same, almost any aggregation function would work.

Answer (score 2):

For your sample data, this will work:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM yourTable
WHERE Column1 = (SELECT MAX(Column1) FROM yourTable)
```

Based on your comment

> and after that the max of column2

You probably want this instead:

```
SELECT Column1, MAX(Column2) as Column2
FROM yourTable
WHERE Column1 = (SELECT MAX(Column1) FROM yourTable)
GROUP BY Column1
```

This handles cases where there are multiple rows with the `MAX(Column1)`, and only returns the row among those with `MAX(Column2)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want the whole row that has the max value of `column1`, try this...

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM   tablename 
ORDER  BY column1 DESC
```

Sample Date

```
+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+---------+---------+
| 1       |       1 |
| 3       |       2 |
| 1       |       3 |
| 2       |       1 |
| 2       |       4 |
+---------+---------+
```

Output

```
+----------+----------+
| Column1  |  Column2 |
+----------+----------+
| 3        |        2 |
+----------+----------+
```

if you want the max values of both `column1` and `column2`, try this...

```
SELECT MAX(column1) as column1, 
       MAX(column2) as column2
FROM   tablename
```

Sample Date

```
+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+---------+---------+
| 1       |       1 |
| 3       |       2 |
| 1       |       3 |
| 2       |       1 |
| 2       |       4 |
+---------+---------+
```

Output

```
+----------+----------+
| Column1  |  Column2 |
+----------+----------+
| 3        |        4 |
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm hard time to interpret your table but there are built-in functions in SQL that would help in your queries.

```
SELECT MAX(column1), MAX(column2)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```